# How to handle session expiry (logically) in ASP Classic and not lose data?

Tags: asp-classic

I've got a system where people grade papers and sometimes they'll leave the keyboard and come back to post - to find out their session has expired. Of course all the data is then lost.

I'd like to at least try to preserve some of that (I have some of the variables from posted form data/query strings).

How do you handle these situations? Are people just screwed if they didn't save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveatrob, in most situations you are right, the user is effectively screwed. Increasing timeout is one thing I have done in the past. I can think of three ideas to get you going.

1) You can try work with the Session_OnEnd function in the Global.asa. This will let you run some code when a session has expired. Unfortunately I don't think it has access to the Request.form collection ... thereby defeating the point.

2) If you wanted to throw caution to the wind, you could always store some encrypted form of the user's identification in a hidden variable on the form. That way if the session in timed-out on the next page .... you can still figure out who submitted the form. Obviously this opens you up to abuse if users figure out they can just impersonate a user by changing form values. A good encryption of their userID/username would probably suffice.

3) Finally, you could change the saving mechanism so that values they are saved (perhaps via AJAX or simply clicking "Save" on each line) as the user inputs them. That way if they fill in half a page, they will have already committed that data to the database.

Frustrating, I know!

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- Increase the timeout
- Use a [`meta refresh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) that will trigger before the timeout so the session stays alive
- Same as `meta refresh`, only using javascript (possibly ajax call), resetting the timer whenever the mouse moves or the keyboard used

Comment: Will the Meta Refresh reload the page and lose any values typed into forms?

Comment: @Caveatrob - It will reload the page. So, depending on the browser, values may be lost.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system with a lot of wizards. We wrote some code to do the following:

1. set a cookie for every unique user
2. store every form value in a simple key-value table in SQL, on a per-user/per-directory base. (so every user has a collection of wizard variables per directory)

If the user logs out, or goes to a different directory (a different wizard) we delete his wizard variables for that directory. We also set a timestamp, so we can delete orphaned variables after a specific time.

All the values are stored as text, we have a library of functions to "cast" them back to the correct format. dates are stored as YYYY-MM-DD, so they always come up correctly, doubles/floats are restored based on the users decimal settings.
This is classic ASP so it's up to the developer to make sure data goes in and out of the wizard correctly.
The developer will also have to remember what wizard variable is a text, which is a date andsoforth.

This is all implemented as a WSC, so it's easy to re-use the code.

It takes some work to set up, but having dozens of wizards makes this a very comfortable solution in our case.

HTH

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be willing to post a little sample code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use a meta refresh from a small inline frame. The iframe page keeps refreshing, keeping their session alive, for as long as they're on the page that they're editing.

You could also achieve the same thing with a timed ajax request from the page that they're using.